# Forge 1.16.5 Mod works in IDE but JAR file crashed game

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, forge

I'm currently trying to modify an already existing mod, and everything works as intended in the IDE (IntelliJ Idea Community). But when I export the jar (via gradle task), it crashes my client and I have this error in the crash-report.

```
Time: 09/11/22 22:43
Description: Mod loading error has occurred

java.lang.Exception: Mod Loading has failed
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.CrashReportExtender.dumpModLoadingCrashReport(CrashReportExtender.java:71) ~[forge:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.server.ServerModLoader.load(ServerModLoader.java:37) ~[forge:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.server.Main.main(Main.java:95) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServerLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLServerLaunchProvider.java:37) ~[forge-1.16.5-36.2.39.jar:36.2] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37) [modlauncher-8.1.3.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54) [modlauncher-8.1.3.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72) [modlauncher-8.1.3.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:82) [modlauncher-8.1.3.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66) [modlauncher-8.1.3.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.runLauncher(ServerMain.java:49) [forge-1.16.5-36.2.39.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.access$100(ServerMain.java:46) [forge-1.16.5-36.2.39.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:43) [forge-1.16.5-36.2.39.jar:?] {}


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: main
Stacktrace:
    at net.tardis.mod.world.structures.TStructures.registerStructurePiece(TStructures.java:173) ~[tardis:1.5.4] {re:classloading}
-- MOD tardis --
Details:
    Mod File: Tardis-Mod-1.16.5-1.5.4.jar
    Failure message: Tardis Mod (tardis) has failed to load correctly
        java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STRUCTURE_PIECE
    Mod Version: 1.5.4
    Mod Issue URL: https://gitlab.com/Spectre0987/TardisMod-1-14/issues
    Exception message: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STRUCTURE_PIECE
Stacktrace:
    at net.tardis.mod.world.structures.TStructures.registerStructurePiece(TStructures.java:173) ~[tardis:1.5.4] {re:classloading}
    at net.tardis.mod.world.structures.TStructures$Structures.<clinit>(TStructures.java:37) ~[tardis:1.5.4] {re:classloading}
    at net.tardis.mod.Tardis.<init>(Tardis.java:138) ~[tardis:1.5.4] {re:classloading}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:67) ~[forge:36.2] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModContainer.lambda$buildTransitionHandler$4(ModContainer.java:106) ~[forge:?] {re:classloading}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {re:computing_frames}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351] {}
```

I haven't modified the file in question (TStructures.java).
Here is the lines around 173:

```java
   public static IStructurePieceType registerStructurePiece(IStructurePieceType type, String key) {
       return Registry.register(Registry.STRUCTURE_PIECE, new ResourceLocation(Tardis.MODID, key), type);
   }
```

And around 37

```java
public static IStructurePieceType DALEK_SHIP_PIECE = registerStructurePiece(DalekShipStructurePieces.Piece::new, "dalek_ship_piece");
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net' }
        maven { url='https://repo.spongepowered.org/repository/maven-public' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '4.1+', changing: true
        classpath group: 'org.spongepowered', name: 'mixingradle', version: '0.7-SNAPSHOT'
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.matthewprenger:CurseGradle:1.4.0"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
apply plugin: 'org.spongepowered.mixin'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "com.matthewprenger.cursegradle"

version = "${mod_version}"
group = "${mod_base_package}"
archivesBaseName = "${project.jar_name}-${minecraft_version}"

java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)

minecraft {
    mappings channel: "${mappings_channel}", version: "${mappings_version}"
    
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')
            arg "-mixin.config=tardis.mixins.json"
            property 'mixin.env.remapRefMap', 'true'
            property 'mixin.env.refMapRemappingFile', "${buildDir}/createSrgToMcp/output.srg"
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'
            mods {
                "${mod_id}" {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')
            property 'mixin.env.remapRefMap', 'true'
            property 'mixin.env.refMapRemappingFile', "${buildDir}/createSrgToMcp/output.srg"
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'
            mods {
                "${mod_id}" {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'
            property 'mixin.env.remapRefMap', 'true'
            property 'mixin.env.refMapRemappingFile', "${buildDir}/createSrgToMcp/output.srg"
            args '--mod', mod_id, '--all', '--output', file('src/main/generated/')
            mods {
                "${mod_id}" {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
    accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')
}

mixin {
    add sourceSets.main, "${mod_id}.refmap.json"
}

repositories{
  maven { url "https://dvs1.progwml6.com/files/maven/" } //JEI Maven
  maven { url "https://maven.blamejared.com/" } // IE Maven
  maven { url "https://www.cursemaven.com" } //Curse Maven
  //maven { url "https://maven.enginehub.org/repo/" } //WorldEdit Maven
  maven { url 'https://modmaven.dev/' } //Mekanism Maven
}

dependencies {
    minecraft "net.minecraftforge:forge:${forge_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.spongepowered:mixin:${mixin_version}:processor"
    //compileOnly fg.deobf("blusunrize.immersiveengineering:ImmersiveEngineering:${ie_version}")
    //runtimeOnly fg.deobf("blusunrize.immersiveengineering:ImmersiveEngineering:${ie_version}")
    compileOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${jei_version}:api")
    runtimeOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${jei_version}")
    runtimeOnly fg.deobf("curse.maven:configured-457570:${configured_version}")
    runtimeOnly fg.deobf("curse.maven:terraforged-363820:3451426")
    //runtimeOnly  ("com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-core:${world_edit_version}")
    //runtimeOnly fg.deobf("com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-forge-mc${world_edit_mc_version}:${world_edit_version}")
    runtimeOnly fg.deobf("mekanism:Mekanism:${mekanism_version}")// core
    runtimeOnly fg.deobf("mekanism:Mekanism:${mekanism_version}:generators")// Mekanism: Generators 
}

//Reference: https://github.com/SizableShrimp/ForgeTemplate/blob/1.16.x/build.gradle#L158-L188
def resourceTargets = ['META-INF/mods.toml', 'pack.mcmeta']
def intoTargets = ["$rootDir/out/production/resources/", "$rootDir/out/production/${project.name}.main/", "$rootDir/bin/main/"]
def replaceProperties = [mod_id: mod_id, mod_name: mod_name, mod_version: mod_version,
                   mod_authors: mod_authors, credits:credits, mod_description: mod_description,
                   display_url:display_url, logo_file:logo_file,
                   issue_tracker_url: issue_tracker_url,
                   update_json_url: update_json_url,
                   license: license,
                   forge_version_range: forge_version_range, minecraft_version_range: minecraft_version_range,
                   loader_version_range: loader_version_range]
processResources {
    inputs.properties replaceProperties
    replaceProperties.put 'project', project

    filesMatching(resourceTargets) {
        expand replaceProperties
    }

    intoTargets.each { target ->
        if (file(target).exists()) {
            copy {
                from(sourceSets.main.resources) {
                    include resourceTargets
                    expand replaceProperties
                }
                into target
            }
        }
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
                "Specification-Title"     : mod_id,
                "Specification-Vendor"    : mod_authors,
                "Specification-Version"   : "1.0.0",
                "Implementation-Title"    : project.name,
                "Implementation-Version"  : mod_version,
                "Implementation-Vendor"   : mod_authors,
                "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"),
                "MixinConfigs": "${mod_id}.mixins.json"
        ])
    }
}

def reobfFile = file("$buildDir/reobfJar/output.jar")
def reobfArtifact = artifacts.add('default', reobfFile) {
    type 'jar'
    builtBy 'reobfJar'
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact reobfArtifact
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file:///${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how this can work in the IDE but not as a JAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out and it seems that the gradle build task in IntelliJ is not from the same gradle so I used `gradlew build` via command line in the project repertory and it built properly.